# error parsing wsdl from maven "[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class." Bindings.xml doesnt recognize xpath

Tags: maven, binding, wsdl, jax-ws

Being new with wsdl parsing, am facing challenge to generate java classes from it. WSDL received from client is non-editable fixed. There isnt any separate xsd, rather all xsd schemas are present in WSDL only.

Issues with my maven build -

```
[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q1:Contact' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 26317 of file:/D:/clientwsdl.wsdl#types?schema18

[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q6:Contact' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 26337 of file:/D:/clientwsdl.wsdl#types?schema18

[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q12:Contact' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 26360 of file:/D:/clientedl.wsdl#types?schema18

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 15913 of file:/D:/clientwsdl.wsdl

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 15883 of file:/D:/clientwsdl.wsdl
```

My bindings.xml

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    jaxb:version="2.0">
    <!-- for warnings like - [WARNING] Simple type "EconomicSector" was not 
        mapped to Enum due to EnumMemberSizeCap limit. Facets count: 804, current 
        limit: 256. You can use customization attribute "typesafeEnumMaxMembers" 
        to extend the limit. -->
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="3000" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

If i update bindings.xml with following additional bindings,

```
<!-- for err like - [ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory 
        class. -->
    <jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::tns"
        xmlns:tns="http://clientdomain.com/v123/NilReport">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.clientdomain.v123.NilReport" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:bindings
            node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='NilReportSummary']">
            <jaxb:class name="CustomNilReportSummary" />
            <!-- Map NilReportSummary to a different name //xs:complexType[@name='NilReportSummary'] 
                //*[local-name()='xs:complexType' and @name='NilReportSummary'] -->
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Then my maven error changes too below inspite of correct xpath -

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='NilReportSummary']" results in empty target node
  line 35 of file:/D:/myinstalls/WS_eclipse/crif-test-wsdl-parse/src/main/java/bindings.xml
```

My pom.xml has only build details as -

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <!-- latest versions doesnt recognize bindings.xml-->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-java-sources</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>
                                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/java/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>
                                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/clientwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Snippet from clientwsdl.wsdl causing build issues -

```
<wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://clientdomain.com/v123/NilReport" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/NilReport">
            <xs:import namespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/Search"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport"/>
            <xs:complexType name="NilReport">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Records" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfNilReportRecord"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Summary" nillable="true" type="tns:NilReportSummary"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="NilReport" nillable="true" type="tns:NilReport"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfNilReportRecord">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NilReportRecord" nillable="true" type="tns:NilReportRecord"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ArrayOfNilReportRecord" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfNilReportRecord"/>
            <xs:complexType name="NilReportRecord">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DateOfInquiry" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Product" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://clientdomain.com/v123/Search" minOccurs="0" name="Reason" type="q1:InquiryReasonsNotSpecified"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReasonText" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q2="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="Sector" type="q2:Sector"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Subscriber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="NilReportRecord" nillable="true" type="tns:NilReportRecord"/>
            <xs:complexType name="NilReportSummary">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NumberOfInquiriesLast12Months" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NumberOfInquiriesLast1Month" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NumberOfInquiriesLast24Months" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NumberOfInquiriesLast3Months" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NumberOfInquiriesLast6Months" type="xs:int"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="NilReportSummary" nillable="true" type="tns:NilReportSummary"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations">
            <xs:import namespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/ContRel"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://creditinfo.com/CB5"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/Inv"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/RelPar"/>
            <xs:complexType name="CurrentRelations">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ContractRelationList" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfContractRelation"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="InvolvementList" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfInvolvement"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RelatedPartyList" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfRelatedParty"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="CurrentRelations" nillable="true" type="tns:CurrentRelations"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfContractRelation">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ContractRelation" nillable="true" type="tns:ContractRelation"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ArrayOfContractRelation" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfContractRelation"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ContractRelation">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/ContRel" minOccurs="0" name="Contact" nillable="true" type="q1:Contact"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FullName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IDNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q2="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="IDNumberType" type="q2:IDNumberTypeAll"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IdScoreId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q3="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/ContRel" minOccurs="0" name="MainAddress" nillable="true" type="q3:MainAddress"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q4="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="RoleOfCustomer" type="q4:RoleOfCustomer"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q5="http://creditinfo.com/CB5" minOccurs="0" name="SubjectType" type="q5:SubjectType"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ValidFrom" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ContractRelation" nillable="true" type="tns:ContractRelation"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfInvolvement">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Involvement" nillable="true" type="tns:Involvement"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ArrayOfInvolvement" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfInvolvement"/>
            <xs:complexType name="Involvement">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q6="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/Inv" minOccurs="0" name="Contact" nillable="true" type="q6:Contact"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FullName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q7="http://creditinfo.com/CB5" minOccurs="0" name="Gender" type="q7:Gender"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IDNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q8="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="IDNumberType" type="q8:IDNumberTypeAll"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IdScoreId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LTV" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q9="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/Inv" minOccurs="0" name="MainAddress" nillable="true" type="q9:MainAddress"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OwnershipShare" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q10="http://creditinfo.com/CB5" minOccurs="0" name="SubjectType" type="q10:SubjectType"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q11="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="TypeOfRelation" type="q11:RelationType"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ValidFrom" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="Involvement" nillable="true" type="tns:Involvement"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfRelatedParty">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RelatedParty" nillable="true" type="tns:RelatedParty"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ArrayOfRelatedParty" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfRelatedParty"/>
            <xs:complexType name="RelatedParty">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q12="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/RelPar" minOccurs="0" name="Contact" nillable="true" type="q12:Contact"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FullName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q13="http://creditinfo.com/CB5" minOccurs="0" name="Gender" type="q13:Gender"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IDNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q14="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="IDNumberType" type="q14:IDNumberTypeAll"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IdScoreId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LTV" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q15="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport/CurrentRelations/RelPar" minOccurs="0" name="MainAddress" nillable="true" type="q15:MainAddress"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OwnershipShare" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q16="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="SubjectStatus" type="q16:SubjectStatus"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q17="http://creditinfo.com/CB5" minOccurs="0" name="SubjectType" type="q17:SubjectType"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q18="http://clientdomain.com/v123/CustomReport" minOccurs="0" name="TypeOfRelation" type="q18:RelationType"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ValidFrom" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="RelatedParty" nillable="true" type="tns:RelatedParty"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
```